# Why can't I extends HTMLElement type for my customize interface using typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using canvas with `typescript` and extends `HTMLElement` for a customize interface, but it show me `Type 'HTMLElement' has no properties in common with type 'MyCanvas'` in terminal, how can I solve it?
By the way, the version of `typescript` is 3.5.3

`index.ts`

```js
import { MyCanvas } from './interface/canvas'
function init (): void {
    const canvas: MyCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 1000
    canvas.height = 1000
}
```

`canvas.ts`

```js
export interface MyCanvas extends  HTMLElement {
    width?:number;
    height?: number;
    getContext: Function;
}
```

Comment: Devil's advocate here; it might just be your minimal example, but do you even need to do this? There is `HTMLCanvasElement` if you want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `document.getElementById` returns `HTMLElement` and this interface cannot be used as a wider interface. You can use `MyCanvas` as `HTMLElement` because `MyCanvas` contains all properties of `HTMLElement` but not in other way around.

Generally the fix is simple, you need to assert the type by `as` keyword to tell the compiler that this function return should be assert to that type.

`const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') as MyCanvas`